# Toaster's "bagel button" does not work. UX or engineering issue?

Tags: physical

Below is picture of my toaster's front panel.

I put bread in, press the "bagel" button, and a bagel does not come out.  I simple get toasted bread.  A bagel is totally different.

I claim this is an engineering issue.  The button doesn't work.  A bagel didn't come out when I pressed the bagel button.

My wife claims this is a UX issue.  She points to the fact that the other buttons are verbs (reheat, defrost, cancel) and that I have assumed that "bagel" is also a verb.

A friend of ours claims this is more of a question for the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
 stack exchange, pointing out that bagel is not a verb as I have assumed.

Who is right?  Me, my wife, or our friend?

[image]

Comment: I also like how turning the knob "up" toward the thicker bars results in lighter or "white" bread, and turning it the other way results in darker or "black" bread.

Comment: If the behavior of the object in question is surprising, confusing, or ambiguous, then there is a UX issue.

Comment: This is a PICNIC problem (person in chair, not in computer [toaster])

Answer (score 3):

First, consider that your description of the problem is incorrect:  when you press the Bagel button, *nothing happens*.  These buttons and knobs are options or modifiers, not actions.  There is only one action control, and that is 'to toast' when you depress the lever. The toasting action is modified by your choices of options.

This is neither an engineering problem nor a language problem.  Out of the three of you, your wife is the most correct by a wide margin, but there is not much of a UX problem here either, as over 99% of people do not suffer from this form of confusion.

All that said, this probably is a poor question for the site.

Comment: I'd like to note that I once had a toaster terrible bagel UX. The button was labeled Bagel, with an icon like this - (| |)  So I put my bagel in the toaster like that, and pushed the button. Unexpectedly, the back of my bagel was toasted, and not the inside like the icon depicted.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2016/03/09